# Como passar um parâmetro do servidor para o client no Datasnap?

Tags: delphi, query, mobile, datasnap

Como eu posso enviar e receber dados usando datasnap?
Eu tenho um banco MySql, uma aplicação Mobile no Delphi Seattle com um servidor datasnap, a conexão funciona e eu consigo pegar os dados do banco e jogar pro celular, porém minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Preciso fazer o login com o Cliente 1 e só vai aparecer os dados desse cliente, dai eu clico no item 1 dele e aparece os dados do item 1 e eu preciso fazer mudanças nesse item, salvar e mandar pro mysql de novo. 
Não sei como fazer esse método no datasnap e chamar no mobile

Comment: tente passar como parâmetro no seu metodo

Comment: Mas eu crio o método com parâmetros no servidor, dai como faço para receber esses parâmetros no celular? tipo, tem que aparecer os dados em cada campo no celular e o usuário vai alterar esses dados, salvar e enviar de voltar pro banco MySql. Não sei como fazer isso de maneira correta

Comment: Faça um metodo no server para retornar um TDataSet e outro para para Receber um TDataSet. Ex.: GetClientes(): TDataSet e outro SetClientes(dtsDados: TDataSet);

Answer (score 1):

Seu `webservice` faz conexão com teu banco de dados e você usa um `SQLconnection`, um `SQLDataset` e um `Datasetprovider`. No `Commandtext` do teu `sqldataset` você inseriu algo como

```
Select * from tabela where id =:id
```

Na tua aplicação mobile, no teu datamodule você colocou `SQLConnection`, drive datasnap, um `DSProviderconnection` e ainda um `ClientDataSet`, no object inspector do `ClientDataSet` você setou o `RemoteServer` pro teu `DSProviderConnection` e no `ProviderName` setou o teu `datasetprovider` lá do seu `webservice`.

Em Params você cria um novo paramentro com o nome de `id`, da um valor 1 pra ele só pra testar, clica com o botão direito do mouse sobre o teu `clientdataset` e clica em `FieldsEditor`, clica com botão direito sobre a área branca da nova janela e clica em Add `Fields`, se carregar todos os campos da tabela é sinal que ta tudo ok passando parametro correto, apague o valor do parametro criado no teu `clientdataset`.

Quando você precisar fazer uma requisição usando paramentro basta usar:

```
 ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 1;
```

Para gravar os dados alterados que foram carregados é aquela velha história de `Post` e `ApplyUpDates()`

Espero que tenha sido útil

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi bem a sua pergunta está meio confusa, mas se foi o que eu entendi é um problema bem simples de se resolver , alias bem primario. os dados do cliente x tem que ser parametrizados de alguma maneira exemplo select * from tabela where cliente =:cliente

ao fazer o login voce pega algum dado do cliente tipo id ou qualquer coisa e usa isso como paramentro.

```
function getPefilUsuario(aUsuario, aSenha: string): Boolean;
begin
  with FQry_Pefil do
  begin
    Close;
    Params[0].AsString := UpperCase(aUsuario);
    Params[1].AsString := UpperCase(aSenha);
    Open;
    Result := (FQry_Pefil.RecordCount > 0);
  end;
```

Se não for isso me desculpe realmente está confusa a pergunta